# How to restrict access to all pages except for two of them

Tags: symfony

I need to block access to any website except for `/` and `/register` so that everyone could access those two, but had to authenticate for the rest.

How can I do that? Nothing I've tried works.

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/(?!(|register))$, role: ROLE_USER }
```

The firewall matches all websites and allows access to all of them.

The access_control section should restrict access to all websites except for `/` and `/register`.

And well, the problem is it doesn't require to log in anywhere, which means I can freely access any url.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```